# Enable/Disable button within DataGrid

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datagrid

this is my first question so I hope anyone can help me.

I want to have a DataGrid table with editable cells, and one button per row that saves the new value once it's changed.

Since I only want to save the changes when there is an edition, I want to start with the buttons **disabled**, and once any edition has been made, **enable** the button.

So... I can detect the button within the handleEditCommit with document.getElementById(...), but when I try to enable it, it doesn't work. How should I approach this?

The DataGrid rows can change, so I don't want to hardcode the buttons and I decided to make them with the renderCell property in a new column.

```
export default function DataTable() {

    const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID' },
        { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', editable: true },
        { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', editable: true },
        { field: 'button', headerName: 'Button', renderCell: (cellValues) => <button id={cellValues.id } onClick={ handleButton } disabled={ true } /> },
    ];

    const rows = [
        { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon' },
        { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei' },
        { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime' },
        { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya' },
        { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys' },
    ];

    const handleButton = (event) => {
        // Button function
    }

    const handleEditCommit = (values, event) => {
        const button = document.getElementById( values.id )
        if ( values.value === rows[ values.id - 1 ][ values.field ] ){
            // Value hasn't changed: Disable button
        }
        else{
            // Value has changed: Enable button
        }
    }

    return (
        <DataGrid
            rows = {rows}
            columns = { columns }
            onCellEditCommit = { (values, event) => handleEditCommit(values, event) }
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are using **@mui/x-data-grid**. Then your setup will be as follows:

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
```

Then, define a **row** state that will keep the edited row reference.

```js
  const [row, setRow] = useState();
```

Next, memoized your **columns** by putting them inside a **useMemo** hook. This is to make sure that the rendered cell will get the latest updated **row** state value.

```js
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      { field: "id", headerName: "ID" },
      { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", editable: true },
      { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", editable: true },
      {
        field: "button",
        headerName: "Button",
        renderCell: (params) => {
          return (
            ...
          )
        }
      }
    ],
    [row]
  );
```

And render the **DataGrid** as follows. Here, the handleEditCommit handler will run on any cell updates. The event will set the **row** with the latest edited row values.

```js
  const handleEditCommit = (values) => {
    setRow(values);
  };

  return (
    <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      autoHeight
      onCellEditCommit={(values, event) => handleEditCommit(values, event)}
    />
  );
```

And finally, render the button in your memoized columns as follows:

```js
  ...
     {
        field: "button",
        headerName: "Button",
        renderCell: (params) => {
          return (
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              size="small"
              disabled={row?.id === params.id ? false : true}
              onClick={() => handleButton(params)}
            >
              Edit
            </Button>
          );
        }
      }
  ...
```

Since your memoized columns will get the latest edited row values, then we can use it as a reference for enabling/disabling **the Edit button**. And here we can pass the **params** to the **handleButton**, do update process, and finally disable the button by reset the **row** value into **undefined**.

```js
  const handleButton = (params) => {
    console.log(params);
    // update the date here
    ...
    // reset the row state
    setRow();
  };

  ...
  
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      ...
      {
        field: "button",
        headerName: "Button",
        renderCell: (params) => {
          return (
            <Button
              ...
              // enabling / disabling button
              disabled={row?.id === params.id ? false : true}
              // pass the params to the handler onClick event
              onClick={() => handleButton(params)}
            >
              Edit
            </Button>
          );
        }
      }
    ],
    [row]
  );
```

And finally, here is the codesanbox. Hope it helps.

[image: Edit eager-dubinsky-vp251d]

Comment: It kind of works, but only when you edit one cell at a time. If you edit multiple cells without saving changed, the buttons start to enable/disable

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the same approach @yohanes suggested, but instead of having a row state that stores the id of the cell edited, it stores an array of all the ids of the cells edited. Therefore, the handleEditCommit method appends the new id to the row, and the handleButton method pops the id value from the array